# IOS: Get Facebook friends who play app

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

I have managed to get the friendslist:

```
//token
NSString *acessToken = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",_facebookAccount.credential.oauthToken];
NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"access_token": acessToken};
// Create the URL to the end point
NSURL *friendsList = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends"];

// Create the SLReqeust
SLRequest *getFriends = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook requestMethod:SLRequestMethodGET URL:friendsList parameters:parameters];
```

I also need need to get which  friends that are playing, but get an error:

```
 me/friends?fields=installed


{
    error =     {
        code = 2500;
        message = "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.";
        type = OAuthException;
    };
}
```

Is there a special permission I need to request for this? I use these now:

```
@"read_stream", @"email", @"read_friendlists"
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get Fb Friend list who use App like bellow method:-

```
- (void)apiRESTGetAppUsers {

    //[self apiGraphFriends];
    NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   @"friends.getAppUsers", @"method",
                                   nil];
    [[objapp facebook] requestWithParams:params
                             andDelegate:self];
}

- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result {


    NSMutableArray *friendsWithApp = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:1];
    // Many results
    if ([result isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
        [friendsWithApp addObjectsFromArray:result];
    } else if ([result isKindOfClass:[NSDecimalNumber class]]) {
        [friendsWithApp addObject: [result stringValue]];
    }




    NSLog(@"Array of all userfrnd of faceboolk   == %@",friendsWithApp);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. Does this code use SLRequest? I don't get the "[[objapp facebook]", Do I need to implement Facebook old SDK for this?

Comment: i use old FBconnect and using my posted Code its working Great.. !

Comment: This solution seems to be using the FB SDK.  Is there an equivalent method within the iOS Social Framework? Using SLRequest, for example?